# Feature extraction with R

Tags: r, feature-extraction, data-cleaning

My question is about feature extraction.

I would like to build a dataframe from my text.

My data is:

```
text <- c("#*TeX: The Program",
      "#@Donald E. Knuth",
      "#t1986",
      "#c",
      "#index68",
      "",
      "#*Foundations of Databases.",
      "#@Serge Abiteboul,Richard Hull,Victor Vianu",
      "#t1995",
      "#c",
      "#index69",
      "#%1118192",
      "#%189",
      "#%1088975",
      "#%971271",
      "#%832272",
      "#!From the Book: This book will teach you how to write specifications of computer systems, using the language TLA+.")
```

My expected output is :

```
expected <- data.frame(title=c("#*TeX: The Program", "#*Foundations of Databases."), authors=c("#@Donald E. Knuth", "#@Serge Abiteboul,Richard Hull,Victor Vianu"), year=c("#t1986", "#t1995"), revue=c("#c", "#c"), id_paper=c("#index68", "#index69"),
                       id_ref=c(NA,"#%1118192, #%189, #%1088975, #%971271, #%832272"), abstract=c(NA, "#!From the Book: This book will teach you how to write specifications of computer systems, using the language TLA+."))
```

Thank you in advance for your answers or any other suggestions.

Comment: What have you tried so far? As far as I see it, you need a way to split this dataset in a structured 2d. How are you loading the data?

Comment: Since you have `abstract` for the second book but not for the first, you either have a problem with your data-acquisition step or you need a clearer way to be *certain* that a particular element in `text` is starting a new entry. For instance, is it **always** the case that `"#*..."` starts a new title? From there, is the next field *always* the author(s)? (Etc, through the other fields in-order.)

Comment: Which class is this? We've seen this data set quite a bit recently and either you've registered multiple accounts after deleting questions (I can link to them if you'd like) or the class is having a super-difficult time but someone, somewhere said this was a great place to get homework help (protip: it generally isn't, and that's not just my opine but the opine of one of the co-founders of SO). I'd honestly like to see any website associated with the class if possible.

Comment: This is not a class. I'm working on a project, and I had a little trouble concatenating part of the table. But thank you for your concern. We are very much working on the same dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I recognize the pattern, though you might need to be clearer about one or two of my assumptions. (I think it is likely that your method for reading in the data could prevent the need for these assumptions, but I don't know for certain.)

First, I'll make a regex "map" of patterns-to-column-name:

```
patterns <- c(title = "^#\\*", author = "^#@",
              year = "^#t", revue = "^#c",
              id_paper = "^#index", abstract = "^#%",
              mismatch = "^([^#]|#[^*@%tci])")
```

Now, assuming that the title is always the first in a sequence of other fields, I'll split the vector into a list of per-title vectors:

```
titles <- split(text, cumsum(grepl("^#\\*", text)))
str(titles)
# List of 2
#  $ 1: chr [1:6] "#*TeX: The Program" "#@Donald E. Knuth" "#t1986" "#c" ...
#  $ 2: chr [1:11] "#*Foundations of Databases." "#@Serge Abiteboul,Richard Hull,Victor Vianu" "#t1995" "#c" ...
```

Now a quick helper-function:

```
standardize_title <- function(x) {
  o <- lapply(patterns, function(ptn) paste(x[grepl(ptn, x)], collapse = ", "))
  o[nchar(o) == 0] <- NA_character_
  o
}
```

And now apply that function to each title of `titles`:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, c(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, lapply(titles, standardize_title)))
#                         title                                      author   year revue id_paper                                        abstract                                                                                                            mismatch
# 1          #*TeX: The Program                           #@Donald E. Knuth #t1986    #c #index68                                            <NA>                                                                                                                <NA>
# 2 #*Foundations of Databases. #@Serge Abiteboul,Richard Hull,Victor Vianu #t1995    #c #index69 #%1118192, #%189, #%1088975, #%971271, #%832272 #!From the Book: This book will teach you how to write specifications of computer systems, using the language TLA+.
```

(One could also use `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist` in place of `do.call(rbind.data.frame, ...)`.)

The biggest assumption of all is that the title is always the first among the patterns. If this is not true, then you *will* get incorrect results, though there will be *no warnings or errors* to such effect.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is correct ! You're a genius !

Comment: Turing, can you please provide some details based on hrbrmstr's comment questions? It is not spurious -- often solving the question you ask is different from solving the actual problem you *have* (an "XY problem"), and getting that kind of detail can really make a difference. If not for you then for those who follow.